# Error: 「default」：internal error: Failed to initialize a valid firewall backend

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, kvm

I in my virt-manager creat a Windows10 VM.
But, it say this:

```
「default」：internal error: Failed to initialize a valid firewall backend

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/netlist.py", line 364, in validate_network
    netobj.start()
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/libvirtobject.py", line 82, in newfn
    ret = fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/network.py", line 81, in start
    self._backend.create()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 2892, in create
    if ret == -1: raise libvirtError ('virNetworkCreate() failed', net=self)
libvirtError: internal error: Failed to initialize a valid firewall backend
```

[image]

How to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install this:

```
sudo apt install uml-utilities
```